# How to run dynamic web projects of Eclipse in Chrome?

Tags: eclipse, google-chrome, web, eclipse-plugin

Before I deleted my previous version of Eclipse Kepler, when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> in Eclipse, while using Dynamic Web Projects, Chrome opened a tab of the project .

However now when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, a tab inside Eclipse is opened.

How can I set Eclipse to open a tab in Chrome when running Dynamic Web Projects?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Go to  `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Web Browser`:

1. first make sure that you are using external web browser
2. then add or choose Chrome to make it *default*.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
Go to windows 
-> choose  Preference 
-> Choose General 
-> WebBrowser 
-> it open an external Dilouge page choose there  Use External Web Browser 
-> then choose chrome/Firefox/Internet Explore
```

Answer (score 1):

you can select option windown > preference > web browser >
Use extenal web brower > Chrome

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqWtx.png)

Hope this can help you!